# sqlalchemy 1.1.10 oracle connection error

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I'm running this code to connect to an Oracle database:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle://user:password@dsn")
engine.execute("select 1 from dual")
```

I get the error message: `'twophase' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`.

I'm using cx_oracle 6.0b1 and SQLAlchemy 1.10.
When I was using cx_oracle 5.2.1 and SQLAlchemy 1.1.5 the code worked

Any idea what's causing this now?

Comment: in your example there is no `twophase`

Comment: I am aware, which makes the error message that much stranger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved - this is an open issue with sqlalchemy, will be solved in the next release

Comment: @Gank yes, as of sqlalchemy 1.11

Comment: The latest is 1.2. Where 1.11 comes from? Could you please give a link? Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, I meant 1.1.11
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/changelog/changelog_11.html
The last row in the 1.1.11 changelog addresses this issue